# Laravel 5 / Lumen Request Header?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, lumen

So I am not really sure how to go about this I have tried a few things and I will list one below however what I am trying to do is store information sent in a http request in a PHP variable.

Here is a view from Chrome Postman of me sending the request I want ot send. Note "pubapi" is a "header".

[image: PostMan View]

I have been messing around with Lumen requests as you can see documented here ( http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/requests ) and have tried using the following below to possibly display them but its not working obviously.

```
echo Request::all();
```

I am putting this in my controller and I have ...

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

in my controller.

So how could I say store the header I am sending "pubapi" into a php variable in my controller?

**EDIT**

Not sure if this will help, however looking at the Laravel frameworks docs I see this http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_header trying this throws the same error in my code. So for example I tried the following and reached the same error.

```
echo Request::header('pubapi');
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try to change the `Illuminate\Http\Request` to `Request`.

```php
- use Illuminate\Http\Request;
+ use Request;
```

Comment: Already had figured it out but figured I would give you best answer for it anyways ha! Thanks!!

Comment: @kmgilbert100, you can use the Illuminate\Http\Request with injection (put a Request $request argument to the controller function. That is the nicest solution I think.)

Answer (score 44):

You misunderstand the Laravel request object on two levels.

First, the error you are getting is because you were referencing the object instead of the Facade. Facades have a way of forwarding static method calls to non-static methods.

Second, you are sending the value as a header but are trying to access the request parameters. This will never give you what you want.

Here is a simple way to see an example of what you want by creating a test route like so:

```
Route::match(['get','post'], '/test', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    dd($request->headers->all());
});
```

Post to this route and you will see your headers, one of which will be *pubapi*. Pay attention that the route method definition matches how you are submitting the request (ie GET or POST).

Let's apply this to the controller, ArticleController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $pubapi = $request->header('pubapi'); // string
        $headers = $request->headers->all(); // array
        /*
          $pubapi === $headers['pubapi']
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Using

```
echo app('request')->header('pubapi');
```

Instead of

```
echo Request::header('pubapi');
```

Seemed to work perfect. Could someone provide additional explanation to why this worked and my original method didn't?

Comment: You're trying to use the Facade, but you're importing the full Request class. Your use statement should be "use Request;" instead of "use Illuminate\Http\Request;" The first is the facade and the second is the actual request class. If you change your use statement then Request::all() will work. Alternatively you can use \Request::all() and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are calling it statically, that's why it is not getting appropriate Request class and throwing error, can do as follows

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

//inside your controller
class YourClass extends Controller{
   public function yourFunction(Request $request){
        //for getting all the request
        dd($request->all());

        //for getting header content
        dd($request->header('pubapi'));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `request()->header('pubapi')` also.

I prefer to use `request()` helper function than `Request` class its self. Because it can be used without `use`/import any class in the controller.